# How to send the ID (unique) in the database through AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I have 3 data in the database (customer table) Which is displayed

My Css  - #form

```
#form{
position:fixed; 
width:320px;min-height:280px;
top:21%;
left:36%;
background-color:#FFF;
padding:10px 10px 20px 10px; 
border:1px solid #AAA;
display:none;
z-index:101;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa;
}
```

I got this code from the net ( the ajax only)

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {

 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","test1.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

And this one is my table display

```
echo "<table width=\"900\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">
    <tr>
         <td>ID</td>
         <td>First name</td>
         <td>Last name</td>
    </tr>";

$query = mysql("SELECT * FROM `reservation` WHERE `CustID` = '$custid'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query){
        $reserveid = $row['ReserveID'];
        $fname = $row['Fname'];
        $lname = $row['lname'];
        $age = $row['age'];

echo "<tr>
         <td>$fname</td>
         <td>$lname</td>
         <td>$age</td>
         <td></td>
         <td><input type=\"image\" src=\"form.png\" onclick=\"\" /></td>
      </tr>";


}
```

My customer table with 3 data

```
|  ID   |  First name  | Last name  |
|   1   |    Anjon     |    Lee     |
|   2   |     Leo      |   Bisnar   |
|   3   |    Joerge    |   Enero    |
```

Can you help me here. 
I got 3 data in my table `customer` with a uniqueID by using the while loop. If I click in the `input` the `loadXMLDoc() occur/tirigger`
and send the `uniqueID` in the test2.php and when the `uniqueID=ID` (AJAX result success) in the database the #form should pop up and display the record

If I click on the first input it should get

```
|  ID  |  First name   |  Last name  |
|   1  |    Anjon      |    Lee      |
```

But the problem is I don't know how to send the uniqueIDs of the displayed data
 Or should I say I am confuse how to do it - PHP to send it through by AJAX is confusing.
Please help me this is for our project

Comment: Associate a row with it's ID in the HTML, e.g. `<tr data-customerid="2"></td>`, when on `<tr>` click, get the attribute, then send the `attributeid` of the clicked element to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=\"image\" src=\"form.png\" reserveid=$resrveid onclick=\"loadXMLDoc(this)\" />

function loadXMLDoc(obj)
{
var rid = obj.getAttribute('reserveid');
var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {

 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","test2.php?id="+rid,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

i hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply premananth. I just test it now and work :)